# Silverlight player for wordpress to support .ism or .isml ( Smooth Streaming from Microsoft )?

Tags: silverlight, wordpress, video-streaming

I'm trying to find a Silverlight player to work in WordPress and also with .isml files ( Smooth Live Streaming ) or .ism files( Smooth Streaming ).

The streaming is Microsoft IIS Streaming.

I tried this one : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/smooth-streaming-player/ , but I can't set the correct path to the .isml file, if I set it, the player crashes.

You can see the example here : http://mundopentecostal.org/?page_id=1900.

Do you happen to know any solutions ?

I would really appreciate one.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [Microsoft Silverlight Media Framework](http://smf.codeplex.com) player.